# How can I get 2 different styles to show on one line in a Table of Contents?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

In my report body, I have a section heading which must be formatted as 2 paragraphs with 2 different styles to start the section.  For example:

Chapter 2 [style A]
Project History [style B]

section body text section body text blah blah blah

Both styles are paragraph styles.  However in the Table of Contents I want them to show up on the same line. For example:

Chapter 2 Project History................p. 10

Or, even better:

Chapter 2, Project History...............p. 10

Does anyone know if this is possible to do automatically?  The only way I can come up with is to make style A and style B both the same TOC level, so they show up as the same TOC style one line right after the other in the TOC, and then manually delete the tab character, page number, and paragraph symbol from the first line so that they are on the same line. But if I update my TOC then I have to re-do this every time.

Thanks for any suggestions! I am using Word 2007 but a solution for Word 2010 would be great also!

Comment: Are you sure the appearance of the two paragraphs requires paragraph styling? If instead you can transfer the formatting to two character styles you could then apply these to the same paragraph (with a line break instead) and the TOC should turn out correctly straight away.